# how to receive multiple input variables in a BPEL process?

Tags: bpel

I want to create a simple BPEL process where in i can enter data into 2 input variables and concatenate it and print it in the output variable.
I did create 2 variable ( default input variable , new_input ) the problem is when i am testing the soa application in OEM . it only shows input box for one of the variables , but not both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you working with Oracle SOA suite ? (OEM = Oracle enterprise Manager ?)
If this is the case, the Oracle solution does not let you control the contract of your SCA components (the WSDL of your BPEL) : your could not have a wsdl with 2 inputs in the same operation.

If both input are from the same source, you have to design an XSD wich describe a complex type  containing both inputed type (simple or complex) and generate your BPEL interface from this XSD as an input type.

If the source of the input are differents, you have to work with a correlation.

about correlation : http://blogs.oracle.com/reynolds/entry/bpel_correlation

Designing BPEL for Oracle SOA Suite : http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/soa/e10224.pdf section 11-2